# How to set up Tsung-recorder proxy on mac os x?

Tags: performance-testing, tsung, tsung-recorder

I am trying to use stung-recorder to record a session on my browser. Seems simple enough but I don't see how to do it. Tsung-recorder says:

```
perftest1(master)> tsung-recorder start
Creating local Tsung directory /Users/pitosalas/.tsung
Creating Tsung log directory /Users/pitosalas/.tsung/log
Starting Tsung recorder on port 8090
perftest1(master)> "Record file: /Users/pitosalas/.tsung/tsung_recorder20150102-2131.xml"
perftest1(master)>
```

But where do I set up port 8090? I can't find it in any doc or answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should set up in browser settings! Example for FF:

1. Open "options"
2. Select "Advanced" -> tab "Network"
3. Click on "Settings.." button for Connections
4. Check "manual proxy configuration:" and type port: 8090 ( and domain
   name )

[image]